# Is Purchases.products use for "Managed In-app Products" in google play api

Tags: google-play, android-billing

In [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html?hl=en-cn#consume), product type has two.
If type is "managed in-app products", we can use [Purchases.products](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/purchases/products/get) this method, if not, we can't use that, is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Order' item type is "inapp", can use Purchases.products;
Order' item type is "subs", can use Purchases.subscriptions